# CSS Center Submenu Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu, navigation

Hi Need to center my 1000px width submenu to the page.

I believe my problem lies in:

```
    position: absolute;
    top: 23px;
    left: 50%;
```

The website is: http://dev.timson.me (Submenus on "Upcoming" & "Past Productions")

And the CSS is:

```
#access {
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto 6px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: Stag;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}

#access ul {
    font-size: 13px;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 0 0 -0.8125em;
    padding-left: 0;

    display:inline-block;
}

.sub-menu {
    text-align: center;
}

#menu-default > li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.sub-menu > li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#access a {
    color: #eee;
    display: block;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-bottom: -4px;
    padding: 0 1.2125em;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#access ul ul {

    display: none;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 23px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 1000px;
    z-index: 99999;
    margin-left:-500px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:10px;

    background: red;
}

#access ul ul a {

    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-bottom:10px;

}

#access ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing `position: relative;` from your main navigation `#menu-default > li` and add `position: relative;` to the main `#access ul`