# Center a submenu with CSS and pointers

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, center, submenu

I have been reading and searching the whole day long. I even read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577616/css-center-submenu-wordpress) and tried to work it out but with no success.

So, what I want to do is a CSS menu with sub menus and have the sub menus centered to the page. [This is what I have done so far](http://art-ebox.com/robust_final/). What I want is that the submenus show up completely centered to the page. Is this possible?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="menu_panel">
  <div id="menu_2border">
    <div id="menu_section">
      <div id='menu1'>
        <ul>
          <li class='first sub'><a href='#'><span>Hem</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Privat</span></a></li>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Om Robust</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class='sub'><a href='#'><span>Koncept</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Insikt</span></a></li>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Koncept</span></a></li>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Aktivering</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class='sub'><a href='#'><span>Uppdrag</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Företag</span></a></li>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Privat</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class='sub'><a href='#'><span>Blogg</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Arkiv</span></a></li>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Kategori</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class='sub'><a href='#'><span>Om Robust</span></a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Vad erbjuder vi?</span></a></li>
              <li><a href='#'><span>Vilka är vi?</span></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class='sub'><a href='#'><span>Kontakter</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#menu_panel {
width:100%;
height: 49px;   
color:#4b4b4b;
display:block;
border-top:#efefef 1px solid;
}

#menu_2border {
width:100%;
border-top:#7a7a7a 1px solid;
}

#menu_section {
width: 960px;
height: 29px;   
margin:auto;
padding: 0 0 0 30px;
color:#4b4b4b;
background-color:#fff;
}

#menu1 ul,
#menu1 li,
#menu1 span,
#menu1 a {
margin: auto;
padding: 0;
position: relative;
}

#menu1 {
height: 29px;
background: #fff;
margin:auto;
}

#menu1:after,
#menu1 ul:after {
content: '';
display: block;
clear: both;
}

#menu1 a {
background: #fff;
color: #4b4b4b;
display: inline-block;
font-size: 15px;
line-height: 29px;
padding: 0px 40px;
text-decoration: none;
}

#menu1 ul {
list-style: none;
/* float: left; */
}

#menu1 > ul > li {
float: left;
}

#menu1 li .mainmenu {
border-right:#d8d8d8 1px dotted;
}

#menu1 > ul > li:hover:after { /* faz as setas debaixo dos items do menu */
content: '';
display: block;
width: 0;
height: 0;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
bottom: 0;
border-left: 8px solid transparent;
border-right: 8px solid transparent;
border-bottom: 7px solid #fff;
margin-left: -10px;
}

#menu1 > ul > li.sub {
border-right:#d8d8d8 1px dotted;
}

#menu1 > ul > li.first {
border-left:#d8d8d8 1px dotted;
}

#menu1 > ul > li:hover > a {
background: #efefef;
}

#menu1 .sub {
z-index: 1;
}

#menu1 .sub:hover > ul {
display: block;
background-color:#
}

#menu1 .sub ul { /* faz o formato das caixas do sub-menu */
display: none;
position: absolute;
width: 803px;
height: 189px;
margin:auto;
border-bottom: #dddddd 1px solid;
border-left: #dddddd 1px solid;
border-right: #dddddd 1px solid;
background: #FFF;
}

#menu1 .sub ul li {
*margin-bottom: -1px;
}

#menu1 .sub ul li a {
background: #fff;
filter: none;
font-size: 13px;
display: block;
line-height: 120%;
padding: 10px 30px;
}
```

Notice that there are pointing arrows in each item of the menu, and they should stay where they are. What should be centered are the big submenu rectangles.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: may be this will help you http://dabblet.com/gist/2792978

Comment: Thanks Sachin but it didn't help. I couldn't adapt it to my case. I know that I could do the menu like I want with jQuery, but I would like to use CSS ONLY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont explicitly understand your situation, do you need something like this? If so, i will make clear understanding on it.

```
#menu1 .sub ul { /* faz o formato das caixas do sub-menu */
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 width: 803px;
 height: 189px;
 margin-left: -401.5px; /* width divided by 2 */
 left: 50%;
 border-bottom: #dddddd 1px solid;
 border-left: #dddddd 1px solid;
 border-right: #dddddd 1px solid;
 background: #FFF;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/hUF4u/1/) / [Screen Result](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/hUF4u/2/embedded/result/)

Comment: No, it's almost but not that. The #menu1 .sub ul shouldn't change place no matter which button I hover with the mouse. I really don't know how to explain it better... The sub menu rectangle has to stay page centered the whole time, no matter what buttun I hover with the mouse...

Comment: agriboz, it worked perfectly, except now the arrows under the 1st level menu items have disapeared... I can't solve this issue, perhaps I have been too many hours looking at it and need a break, do you have any idea what happened? This is the piece of code that should be doing the arrows:

`#menu1 > ul > li:hover:after {
   content: '';
   display: block;
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   position: relative;
   left: 50%;
   bottom: 0;
   border-left: 8px solid transparent;
   border-right: 8px solid transparent;
   border-bottom: 7px solid #fff;
   margin-left: -5px;
}`

Comment: I don't understand. I have done exactly like you have in your example (copy/paste), but when I save it and upload it the result is not the same... Now the rectangles (level 2 of the menu) come up slightly out of place (about 20px to the left). Any clue of what is my mistake?

Comment: You need to give `ul`s `padding:0`. I checked the mark on jsfiddle **[normalize](http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/)** to make browser behave more consistently.

Comment: BEAUTIFUL abriboz!!!!!! I don't know how to thank you except to say THANKS!! You're the boss!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply `absolute` positioning to your drop down menu, and have it relate to your top-level menu by applying `relative` positioning *only* to it. That direct relationship means you can set your drop-down menu to `left: 0` and `right: 0`, sticking it to the left-most side and right-most side respectively of the top-level menu regardless of where it appears in your HTML (ie. it will match the width of your top-level `ul`).

Because you have set `position:relative` to a number of items, and some of your code might be dependant on that, I can't easily change your code to make it work. However, I put together this quick demonstration on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bMyVs/) to illustrate my explanation. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much John! I did tried your way, but from the moment on I put the `right: 0` my level 2 of the menu was just streching to a width bigger than the menu's. Fortunately I already manage to solve the problem, you can check the first answer which I already marked as correct.